# Checkbox boolean always returning false in WPBakery

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, wpbakery

I've created a custom element for the WPBakery plugin. I have mapped out a simple checkbox for this element:

```
array(
    'type' => 'checkbox',
    'heading' => esc_html__( 'Add box shadow?', 'js_composer' ),
    'param_name' => 'add_boxShadow',
    'value' => array('Yes' => 'true'),
    'std' => false,
    'description' => esc_html__('Ticking this will add a shadow below the row.'),
    'group' => __( 'Custom', 'my-text-domain' ),
)
```

And I have initialised it like so:

```
$output = ""; 
extract(
      shortcode_atts(
        array(
          'add_boxShadow' => false,
          // 'add_boxShadow' => '', have also tried this
        ),
      $atts
      )
    );
```

And outputting like this:

```
<?php 
$shadowBottom = "";
($add_boxShadow = true ? $shadowBottom = "shadow__bottom" : ""); 

$output .= '<div class="wrapper'.$shadowBottom.' "> test </div>';
return $output;
?>
```

**With the above, I'm having the following issues:**

1. A `var_dump($add_boxShadow)` returns `bool(false) bool(false)`. My guess that's because when the var is initialised, the $add_boxShadow is set to false (`'add_boxShadow' => false`). However, I've done this so that the checkbox is unticked my default.
2. In the WPBakery page builder, this is how the field looks:

[image]

Which is good, it's unchecked by default which is what I want. However, if I then tick the checkbox, save and update the page, when I go back to that blocks setting, the checkbox is still unticked. Almost as if it's always being rendered false?

Answer (score 0):

std options will be false by default. So you dont need to write the false one. Another thing I found that you missid out the shorcode name in `shortcode_atts` method, which may be another reasons for your problem. Please find the below code which helps :

```
   array(
        'type' => 'checkbox',
        'heading' => esc_html__( 'Add box shadow?', 'js_composer' ),
        'param_name' => 'add_boxShadow',
        'value' => array('Yes' => 'true'),
        'description' => esc_html__('Ticking this will add a shadow below the row.'),
        'group' => __( 'Custom', 'my-text-domain' ),
    )
```

---

```
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
                    'add_boxShadow'=>'',
                ), $atts,'<shrotcodename>' ) );


  if($ze_coming_soon_days=='Yes') //code for yes
  {
    //code
  }
```